# jQuery Ajax Post, Add them to DB, Return Data and repeat the Process again

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, post

I'm completely confused so please let explained the logic clearer.

Here where i get my data from db.

```
index.php


    $sorular_hepsi = mysql_query("select * from tblsorular where hafta=1 order by rand() limit 2");
    $soru_ust = mysql_fetch_assoc($sorular_hepsi);
    $soru_id = $soru_ust_rs["id"];
    $soru_grup_id = $soru_ust["sId"];

    $soru1 = $soru_ust["soru"];

    $sorular = mysql_query("select * from tblsorular where sId=$soru_grup_id");
    $totalKayit = mysql_num_rows($sorular_rs);

    while ( $sorular_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($sorular)) {
        $sorular2[] = $sorular_rs["soru"];
        $sorular2Id[] = $sorular_rs["id"];
    }

$userId = 1234;
```

And here is the listed objects in `index.php`

```
    <div id="sorugonder" class="soruStyle">
        <a href="#" class="sorugonder" id="<?=$sorular2Id[0]?>"><?=$sorular2[0]?></a>
    </div>

    <div id="soru_sag" class="soruStyle">
        <a href="#" class="sorugonder2" id="<?=$sorular2Id[1]?>"><?=$sorular2[1]?></a>
    </div>
```

And here is my ajax function to send my data to `islem.php`

```
$(function() {
    $(".sorugonder").click(function() {
    // $('#load').fadeIn();
    var commentContainer = $(this).parent();

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var string = 'id='+ id ;

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "islem.php?islem=soruKayit",
       data: string,
       cache: false,

       success: function(data){

       commentContainer.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
             $('#sorugonder').fadeOut(1000);
             $('#soru_sag').fadeOut(2000);

             console.log(string);
             // alert(id);
            }
        });

        return false;

    });
});
```

This function printing console log as `id=xx`

And here is my islem.php page to get ajax data

```
if(isset($_POST["islem"]) && $_POST["islem"]=="soruKayit"){

    header('Content-type: application/json');

    $id= $_POST['string'];
    $cevapTarihi = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");

    $cevapId = json_encode($id);
    $userId = 1234;

     $kayit = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblk_skor VALUES(NULL, $userId,$cevapId,$cevapTarihi)");

        if(!$kayit){
                echo "Error:".mysql_error();
        }

        die();

   }
```

I've 4 different png pictures and i'm using them as a background for them. For example :

```
$1 = '<img src="../img/1.png" />';
$2 = '<img src="../img/2.png" />';
$3 = '<img src="../img/3.png" />';
$4 = '<img src="../img/4.png" />';
```

I have change my listed datas background on each post process. But i couldn't figure it out how and where i have to put them?

$.ajax function doesn't send my data to islem.php or i can't get it.

Simply :

1. I want to add my record to database (just id )
2. I have to execute callback function to repeat this process 10 times with 10 different records.
3. After finish this 10rec i'm going to calculate the results and redirect to another page.
4. Changing backgrounds every post step.
5. Countdown! I have to put countdown into a div to users click it in 10 seconds. Otherwise i have to execute another error function to start all this again. I couldn't find a proper countdown script to demonstrate on my functions.

Just this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `data` option in `ajax` is supposed to contain the data you want to send to the server.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "islem.php",
   data: [{ name:'islem', value:'soruKayit' },
          { name:'id', value:id }],
   cache: false,
   ....
```