# jQuery checkbox validation without form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, checkbox

I want to make a validation function with jQuery or pure javascript.

this is my checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms">
```

and this is my link button

```
<label id="kosullar" for="terms">
<a class="fancybox-effects-d" data-fancybox-type="iframe" onclick="" href="kosullar.php">KULLANIM  &nbsp;KOSULLARINI  &nbsp;KABUL&nbsp; EDIYORUM</a>
</label>
```

If checkbox is checked process will continue to redirect my `href` url if not i want to show alert() to user.

Thats it.

Would you show me an example?

Comment: Please don't post answer within your question, especially when the accepted answer is already posted below.  If the accepted answer is not correct or complete, please feel free to post & accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
     function Accept(dat){

            var terms = $('#terms').is(':checked');

            if(terms){
                window.location.href=dat.href;
            }else{
                alert('not checked!');
                return false;
            }
      }
```

HTML Section:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms">

    <label id="kosullar" for="terms">
        <a class="fancybox-effects-d" data-fancybox-type="iframe" onclick="return Accept(this);" href="kosullar.php">KULLANIM  &nbsp;KOSULLARINI  &nbsp;KABUL&nbsp; EDIYORUM</a>
    </label>
```

Another method:

```
 $(function(){

      $(".fancybox-effects-d").click(function(){

           var terms = $('#terms').is(':checked');

            if(terms){
                window.location.href=$(this).attr('href');
            }else{
                alert('not checked!');
                return false;
            }
        });

   });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms">

    <label id="kosullar" for="terms">
        <a class="fancybox-effects-d" data-fancybox-type="iframe"  href="kosullar.php">KULLANIM  &nbsp;KOSULLARINI  &nbsp;KABUL&nbsp; EDIYORUM</a>
</label>
```

Comment: users aren't clicking the checkbox.. there is another <a> tag below it.

Comment: your code is working like a charm...but is there any way to assign onclick to another <a> tag like <a class="fancybox-effects-d" data-fancybox-type="iframe" onclick="return Accept(this);"  href="katilim.php"> ... what should i write to Accept(HERE) instead?

Comment: Thank you. Its working but it has made another problem :) when user is clicked the begin button (<a>) it shows alert if its not checked. But if its checked function is redirecting my href to new page. Normally its opening with fancybox. How can i make it? i mean opening this after checking process with fancybox again.?

Comment: You remove the else condition, Add fancybox function instead of window.location.href tag

Comment: I added my final code as a solution to my question. Thank you again.

Comment: @Chunnu Would you please check it out? If you know jquery ajax? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818176/jquery-ajax-post-add-them-to-db-return-data-and-repeat-the-process-again/19818522?noredirect=1#19818522

Answer (score 1):

In your `onclick` define a function and pass `this`, `return false` to stop the default action

```
onclick="verifyCheck(this); return false;"

function verifyCheck(elem) {
    var cb = document.getElememtById("terms");

    if (cb.checked) { 
        location.href = elem.href;
    } else {
         alert("Check the box!");
    }
}
```

Comment: your function will work but it doesn't right now. because <a> is redirecting my link to fancybox. And i want to execute it after the validation is complete. How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.fancybox-effects-d').click(function(e) {
    if (!($('#fancybox-effects-d').is(':checked'))) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Tyagi, do you think you can add value to this answer with an explantion for the OP?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 <a class="fancybox-effects-d" data-fancybox-type="iframe" onclick="return Validate();" href="kosullar.php">
```

Javascript method

```
function Validate()
{
 If($("#terms").is(":checked"))
 {
    //do your code to go to next step
 }
 else
 {
  alert("Please check the checkbox");
  return false;
 }
}
```